# Should I make a non-indexed table for the sake of form?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm in the middle of setting up a database, and I've run into a situation where it makes more sense to make a separate table for entries. However, it doesn't actually make sense to index this table. I could just merge this table with another table, but I believe it would be poor form (works for this project, but would not be universally workable).

Any tips or suggestions? The specifics are that the indexed table keeps track of "games", with a GameId AI. The table in question would have a separate entry for each player (so a table like PlayerGame).

Thanks!

Comment: Entire tables are not indexed, but individual columns.  Presumably you would index the column(s) used in joins

Answer (score 3):

Indexes must be added on gameid and playerid

Comment: Can you elaborate please? Each game would have multiple entries for each player (two, three, four, etc players per game). How would I construct the table with indexes?